# How to run custom django-admin manage.py command

Tags: python, django

I would like to run my custom command with more than one city's id. How to I do that? I didn't find anythind in the documentation. This is source code of my command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from reservation.models import City

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('city_id', nargs='+', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for city_id in options['city_id']:
            try:
                city = City.objects.get(pk=city_id)
            except City.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError('City "%s" does not exist' % city_id)

            print city
```

This command works pretty well for `python manage.py command_name 1`. It prints city with id=1. But I would like to print city with id 1,2.. without executing the same command multiple times. It is `python manage.py command_name 1, 2` or `python manage.py command_name [1,2,3]`. Something like this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just realized that I should execute:

> python manage.py command_name 1 2 3

to print city with id 1, 2 and 3.